# How to use a more recent version of nautilus on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

A bug has been introduced in Nautilus 4 years ago, where opening a multi-selection of files with an app launches N instances of the app, instead of opening the N files in a single instance (previous/desired behaviour).

It was finally fixed 2 months ago: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/commit/080f83385ff79a8be54ee31e7a45422138226f1f, a bit before version 40rc.

How do I install the more recent nautilus (say 40.1) on Ubuntu 20.04?
I currently have nautilus 3.36.3

I've googled around, and people mention [adding the gnome3 ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760309/how-do-i-upgrade-gnome-files-nautilus-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04), but it doesn't have any binaries for focal.

Is my only resort to build it from source?

Comment: So, Ubuntu 20.04 has a Gnome 3 desktop. But your desired Nautilus version (40.1) looks like that it may depend on Gnome 4? That would be a big endeavor to upgrade to Gnome 4, wouldn't it? (I don't know.) (Here you can see gnome-shell having a Gnome-4 (precisely, gnome-40) branch: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/tree/gnome-40/)

Comment: This is a thread about when gnome-40 may show up in Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1342446/1157519

Comment: For focal there is [only one PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lubomir-brindza/+archive/ubuntu/nautilus-typeahead?field.series_filter=focal) with Nautilus, and it ships 3.36. Also you can't get v40 on focal because of API changes and deep dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried installing the flatpak version?